# Script to find and grep the group

Tags: python, bash, scripting, ksh, nis

I am struggling to write a bash script or python script to find a string from a file.

For example, I need to search for `usrname4` and if it found then I need fetch its group. In this case, it is `group1`. Since the file format is tricky i am looking after some hints.

The file contents are in below format.

```
group1    (-,usrname1,abc.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname1,xyz.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname2,abc.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname2,xyz.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname3,abc.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname3,xyz.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname4,abc.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname4,xyz.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname5,abc.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname5,xyz.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname6,abc.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname6,xyz.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname7,abc.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname7,xyz.co.uk)\
group2    (-,usrname8,abc.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname8,xyz.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname9,abc.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname9,xyz.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname10,abc.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname10,xyz.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname11,abc.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname11,xyz.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname12,abc.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname12,xyz.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname13,abc.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname13,xyz.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname14,abc.co.uk)\
          (-,usrname14,xyz.co.uk)\
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: read the file line by line, if a line contains a group extract it and store it to a variable. If a line contains the desired username you can break out of the loop, your target group is the content of the variable. Can be easily implemented in pure bash (while read line loop), awk or even sed (using its hold buffer to store the group)

Comment: Hello Wogsland and Andeas, Apologies if my ask is not in proper way. Actually, i have been putting lot of pseudo codes to achieve this. But could not succeed. Hence i asked here to get some light. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following specifications:

- A group can be found by looking for the a line that starts without a space
- A group name is without spaces
- When username occurs more than once, only look at the first one
- Search for the last group mentioned before the match

First select all groups and all matched lines.
From that set look for the last line before the first match, that must be the group.

```
usr=usrname4
grep -Eo "^[^ ]+|,${usr}," file | grep -B1 ",${usr}," | head -1
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks Walter for your response. It is working. But, if i have a username in two groups it is still giving first group not giving other group. Could you please help me in getting all the groups in which the given username belongs to?

Comment: Replace `head -1` with `egrep -Ev "^--$|^,"`.